# Ionic-React: Not able to customize single IonSelectOption with CSS class

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-react

I'm trying to customize a single IonSelectOption with a custom CSS class to change the color of one IonSelectOption. I am copy-pasting the code from Ionic's documentation but it still isn't working. The CSS className that I provide to the IonSelectOption does not seem to get passed along to whatever interface that it selected. Hope someone can help me out!

[Link to Documentation.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select-option#customizing-individual-options) This is the code I'm using:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { IonContent, IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption, IonPage } from '@ionic/react';

const options = {
  cssClass: 'my-custom-interface'
};

export const SelectOptionExample: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <IonItem>
          <IonLabel>Select</IonLabel>
          <IonSelect interface="popover" interfaceOptions={options}>
            <IonSelectOption value="brown" class="brown-option">Brown</IonSelectOption>
            <IonSelectOption value="blonde">Blonde</IonSelectOption>
            <IonSelectOption value="black">Black</IonSelectOption>
            <IonSelectOption value="red">Red</IonSelectOption>
          </IonSelect>
        </IonItem>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

and the CSS:

```css
/* Popover Interface: set color for the popover using Item's CSS variables */
.my-custom-interface .brown-option {
  --color: #5e3e2c;
  --color-hover: #362419;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in react, it is `className`, not `class`

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't the issue. Tried both ways. The 'class' must be an error in their documentation.